# how to convert all datetimes from a dataframe in a specific format in a Python pandas datetime dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dataset

i have a dataframe with 1.000.000
there is a column called "datetimes".
The problem is that the half datetimes follow this format:

```
2022-month-day hour-minutes-seconds
```

and the rest datetimes follow this format

```
2022-day-month hour-minutes-seconds
```

does anybody knows what i have to add in my code in order to have this ouput
i want all the datetimes to be with this format:
`2022-MONTH-DAY`
a sample of my dataframe is
Datetime
0   2022-09-06 12:33:40
1   2022-09-06 12:33:50
2   2022-09-06 12:34:00
.
.
.
10.000 2022-09-06 23:59:50
.
.
55251   2022-06-15 22:02:20
55252   2022-06-15 22:02:30
55253   2022-06-15 22:02:40
55254   2022-06-15 22:02:50
.
.
311492  2022-07-15 13:52:20
311493  2022-07-15 13:52:30
311494  2022-07-15 13:52:40
.
.

537534  2022-10-08 17:47:00
537535  2022-10-08 17:47:10
537536  2022-10-08 17:47:20

as you can see the formation of the datetime changes many times

Comment: It might be difficult to identify which format is which, for instance `2022-05-02` is 2022-month-day or 2022-day-month? It would be useful also if you include in the question a sample from your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

So since I'm a beginner, idk if my answer helps, but if you could show your code it would also be helpful to see if you didn't write something wrong or if something's missing.

I did this small snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

date = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["18-12-2022", "19-12-2022", "20-12-2022"]})

date["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(date["Date"]).dt.strftime('2022-%m-%d')

print(date)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date
0  2022-12-18
1  2022-12-19
2  2022-12-20
```

Hope it helps.